# crash in GADMutableArrayAddObject

Tags: swift, ads, googleads-mobile-unity

My app crash when first open with Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (9.11.0).

[image: crash GADMutableArrayAddObject]
Any answer will be appreciated.

I found a similar question here. But don't have any answers.
https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/6DXqfzd6_V4.